# How to load data into array and load into data table using loop?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, for-loop

I am having a for loop to push data into array and then load that data into datatable. 
Mycode for loop is below:

```
var arr = [];
var Id =1;
for(i=startdate1; i < enddate1; startdate1.setDate(startdate1.getDate() + 1)){
if (New_SDate == DWD_2) {
arr.push(([
Id,
startdate1,
'testing'
]));
Id++;
}
}

var t=$("#table").datatable;
for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
t.row.add([
arr[i][0],
arr[i][1],
arr[i][2]
]).draw();
}
```

If my condition satisfies means, my array needs to store data as

```
{Id=1, Startdate1=1/1/2019, 'testing'}
{Id=2, Startdate1=8/1/2019, 'testing'}
{Id=3, Startdate1=15/1/2019, 'testing'}..
```

when I debug, it loads correctly, but the final output displays as

```
Id=1, Startdate1=31/12/2019, 'testing'
Id=2, Startdate1=31/12/2019, 'testing'
Id=3, Startdate1=31/12/2019, 'testing'..
```

which means , it displays the last 'startdate1' value to  whole startdate1. What I did wrong.? Kindly help.

Comment: try to console the data so you can check that coming data is perfect or not if the date is coming correct then the problem is converting the date range

Comment: I never convert date range, when debug, it load date of 7 days once date to array, and Id also comes correct with counting, only the startdate1 date comes as last date for all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should increment the iterator and convert the value to Date.

```
for(i=startdate1; i < enddate1; i.setDate(i.getDate() + 1)){
arr.push(([
Id,
new Date(i),
'testing'
]));
Id++;
}
```

Comment: What are the values you are using as startdate1 and enddate1 to get the given output?

Comment: `var startdate = y + '-01-01';
var startdate1 =new Date(startdate);` y indicates selected year. likewise enddate as  `var enddate = y + '-12-31';
                 var enddate1 =new Date(enddate);` the loop works fine for whole selected year, only the output comes wrong\

Comment: Your updated answer working for me thank you. Why its not working earlier